# ELectron React Boilerplate random error at start

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, electron

I have a project, very simple, based on ERB, but 50% of the time I started I get the following error in the (webkit) console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')
    at Object.injectIntoGlobalHook (react-refresh-runtime.development.js:449:1)
    at Object../node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/client/ReactRefreshEntry.js (ReactRefreshEntry.js:17:1)
    at Object.options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at startup:4:1
    at startup:10:1
    at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (universalModuleDefinition:7:1)
    at universalModuleDefinition:10:2
```

The application starts, load a blank screen with the above error in the console.

In the terminal I see the following messages:

```
08:21:21.774 > Skip checkForUpdatesAndNotify because application is not packed
<i> [webpack-dev-middleware] wait until bundle finished: /index.html
[19072:0519/082130.210:ERROR:CONSOLE(160)] "Electron sandbox_bundle.js script failed to run", source: node:electron/js2c/sandbox_bundle (160)
[19072:0519/082130.210:ERROR:CONSOLE(160)] "TypeError: object null is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))", source: node:electron/js2c/sandbox_bundle (160)
```

The crazy thing is that yesterday before closing the PC it was working fine, this morning, I've run it again without making any change, the same code as yesterday, and I get the error.

Please give me some hint because I really don't know what to search for!